# Application spyder launch may have produced errors

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to launch **Spyder** from **Anaconda** and keep getting the error copied below. I tried updating python.app, installing **Python 3.6.5** and other suggested solutions but had no luck.

Any suggestions?

I'm trying to launch **spyder 3.2.4** on **macOS Mojave 10.14.2.**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/fagarrido/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/fagarrido/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWebEngineWidgets.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libQt5WebEngineCore.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/fagarrido/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWebEngineWidgets.so
Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/fagarrido/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/fagarrido/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 144, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "/Users/fagarrido/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 92, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "/Users/fagarrido/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 26, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage as QWebEnginePage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'
```